# Как найти слова в строке колонки sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Все никак не могу понять ...

Получается у меня есть таблица, даю отрывок. Мне надо найти ТОЛЬКО фамилию, а программа думает иначе и выдает результат None или []:

```
id, fullname 

1, Василий Булгаков Дмитриевич

2, Мария Терехова Ивановна
```

Использую команду

```
f = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname = '%Булагаков%'").fetchall()

rows = f

    for row in rows:

        print(str(row))
```

**Но оно не находит, но за то находит если вводить ФИО полностью, а мне нужно именно фамилию, что делать?**

Comment: Там, наверное, так надо `fullname LIKE '%Булагаков%'`

Comment: Всё впринципе правильно говорите, но у меня в базе 10 миллионов строк, и он выбивает все строки (возможно не по порядку, а какие-то определённые) не содержащие в строке фамилию Булгаков. Хотя пробовал делать вот так 'Булгаков%' и только по началу строк оно выбило все, но мне надо не только по началу строки, но и в середине или конце строки находить